# Upgrade App Engine servlet-api-2.5 to servlet-api-3.1?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

With the recent announcement of support for Servlet 3.1, I cannot figure out how to modify the App Engine Standard environment to use 3.1 instead of 2.5 in a non-Maven build.

It seems there is no way to upgrade to 3.1?

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/Google-App-Engine-standard-now-supports-Java-8.html

Comment: can you please post your gradle build file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a **full example given here**: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/helloworld

Running procedure is also attached.

### For Gradle Users:

**For non-maven users, you can use gradle.**

In gradle build file, line number 39 denotes: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/blob/master/appengine-standard-java8/helloworld/build.gradle#L39

```
providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
```

**Running locally:**

> gradle appengineRun

If you do not have gradle installed, you can run using **./gradlew appengineRun**.

To use visit: http://localhost:8080/

### For Maven Users

In pom.xml, **line number 62 to 70** denotes that it is using **servlet version 3.1.0**: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/blob/master/appengine-standard-java8/helloworld/pom.xml#L66

```
<!-- [START servlet] -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- [END servlet] -->
```

Hope it will clarify you.

Comment: @MarCialR I have mentioned for maven and non-maven users so that it can help others who are falling in same error for maven.

Comment: This answer was especially helpful since it explained I need gradle as well. Thank you.

Comment: This wasn't working for me in my Cloud Endpoints project until https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/pull/129 was released in 2.0.12.

Answer (score 3):

These are the steps that should work no matter what technique is used, as long as it produces a valid war that includes javax.servlet-api:3.1.0:

1) [As documented](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8#specifying_the_java_8_runtime_for_your_app), make sure you've added `<runtime>java8</runtime>` to your appengine-web.xml file

2) uncompress the war into its own separate directory

3) deploy using the appcfg.sh script found on [App Engine SDK for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download) bin directory. It will look something like:

`/<some-path>/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54/bin/appcfg.sh update /<some-path>/exploded-war/`

Note: To verify ServletContext's version from within a servlet I've used:

```
ServletContext sc = req.getSession().getServletContext();
resp.getWriter().println("Servlet version = " + sc.getMajorVersion() + "." + sc.getMinorVersion());
```